# How can I improve the responsiveness of buttons in an iPad kiosk web app?

Tags: ios, ipad, web-applications, kiosk

I developed a web app for our iPad 2 kiosks that just went live today.  Pretty much all of our clients are having problems using the touchscreen.  They are pounding on the buttons and the app is not registering a touch.

I had never thought there would be so much difficulty for a user to interact with the touch screen.  I am wondering if there is anything I can do as a developer to make this more user friendly.  There is a slight lag between the touch and it actually getting registered - which is making it that much more difficult for the user to know they have pressed a button.

I can safely say, the buttons are plenty big - in fact probably larger than what the iOS guidelines would be (again this is a web app - it isn't written in Objective-C, rather PHP and jQuery).  All the action is happening in the web app - which is accessed using a simple UIWebView iOS app that simply connects to the site.

To clarify, there are 2 problems:

1. Touch not registering at all - clients press progressively harder in frustration
2. For touch events that are registered, there is a lag

Thanks to some suggestions in the comments below, which eventually led me to this [link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-remove-the-300ms-delay-when-clicking-on-a-link-in-jquery-mobile), I was able to greatly improve the responsiveness of the web app.  But I know my code could still be improved.  My app uses a combination of backbone.js and jquery outside of any of the backbone mvc.

Here is an example of a jquery event I altered to prevent the default touchend behavior (it originally was a click event).

```
$('body').on( 'touchend', '#s-id', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('form[name=client-login]').submit();
});
```

And an example of a backbone view, which also originally used a click event

```
        var CounterView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: "body",

        events: {
            "touchend #b-q-prev": "qPrev",
            "touchend #b-q-next": "qNext"
        },

        qNext: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();                 
            this.model.qIncrease();
            this.qShow();
        },

        qPrev: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();                         
            this.model.qDecrease();
            this.qShow();
        },...etc...
```

Implementing these techniques solved both my problems, as the app essentially doesn't care what you do after you originally touch a button, once you release it considers the original button you touched was pressed.  This allows the haphazard taps my clients use to trigger the events.  It also is way faster, solving issue 2.

I am not confident I have implemented this correctly.  One major downside is now that when I do testing with a non-touch device, no events register because I removed all click events from the java script.  Should I be looking at multiple events, not just blocking the default touch end?  Based on the research I did, there is no clear solution to this - as jquery mobile hasn't event implemented it yet?

Comment: Since it is live, can you share the URL so we can see what you are referencing?

Comment: Try to minimise the lag between the touch and the response to the touch?

Comment: @Jeremey1026 it is on our internal network - not publicly visible

Comment: @onnoweb How can I minimize the lag - also even registering a touch at all is a problem

Comment: Note that on iOS there is a 250ms delay in firing the onclick event as the OS tries to wait and see if you are actually going to scroll or something else instead.  Depending on your needs, you might be able to listen for a mousedown event or similar instead and avoid the 250ms delay. https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons?hl=de-DE

Comment: @scunliffe - thank you for this excellent resource, I'm guessing this will at least partially solve my issue.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question perfectly, but the problem may not be the touch responsiveness, but rather than time it takes for your web application to give the user a visual response. If I'm right about this, and there's nothing you can do about the speed of the response, perhaps you need some other visual indication that the button has been pressed, such as an ajax spinner.

Comment: Have you tried binding the form submission to the touchstart function instead of to touchend? Touchend only fires after they lift their fingers up. Touchstart happens instantly. You might even use them in conjunction where touchstart sets the current time to a global variable, and the touchend will do the form submission if a call to new Date().getTime() is >= the touchstarts's current Time variable + X milliseconds to prevent accidental taps.